# C++: how do I create istream with desired content?

Tags: c++, stream

I was given a function with following signature. I can't change it, I have to work with it.

```
void parse(std::istream & in);
```

I'm supposed to test this function, so basically call it with predefined content and check if the values were properly parsed. Therefore I need to call this function... something like `parse("abcdedf....")`... but I wasn't able to to find a way how to do it.

I'm new to C++ so this may be a dumb question. As far as I understand streams, istream is something that I get when reading from a source, a file for example. So I need to turn regular string into this source but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::istringstream iss("abcdef....");
parse(iss);
```

Like `std::ifstream`, used for reading in files, `std::istringstream` derives from `std::istream`, so you can upcast a `std::istringstream &` to a `std::istream &` to pass in.

Comment: Thanks.. but could you please write the full source, including the upcast part?

Comment: @tobik, That's all you need. The upcast happens implicitly.

Comment: Oh, I was blind :-) there was a problem with another parameter in this function (I used " instead of ' for char) and I thought the compiler message was there because of this weird istream. Thanks, it's working now.